# Code with random number generator and loop

Tags: java, random, generator

I use this random number generator and it works fine but then I needed a range (e.g. 16-20) of numbers but I can't get it to work. I have no idea what to do.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
    int RandomAttack = (int) Math.random() * 20;
    System.out.println(RandomAttack);
}
```

I need the simplest code there is.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= 1 ; i++)`? What's the point of doing a loop with just one iteration? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you mean `int RandomAttack = 16 + (int)(Math.random()*5);`

Comment: If you will have a loop with 1 unique iteration then you could to remove the loop

Comment: Peter Lawrey, it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Would have been better to close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java, but I came too late with my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Math.random() will only return numbers in range 0..1. You could scale this by multipling by range and adding on minimum.

Or use java.util.Random(), this has a handy method [nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt()) which will return between 0 and < value.

So you need to go 0<= value < 5 to have values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            int value = 16 + random.nextInt(5);
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have your Random imported and initialised, `Random random = new Random();`

Follow:

```
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(max - min) + min;
```

In your case

```
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(20 - 16) + min;
```

That alone should get you your desired value within range. Don't forgot to import Java's Random class on top of your class.

Also, I'm not quite understanding the point of your loop over there. Am I missing something obvious or is that just one iteration?

---

Here is a class example:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomRange {
    private static Random random;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        random = new Random();

        System.out.println(random.nextInt(20 - 16) + 16);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah. actually it only is one iteration because it's supposed to be like hitpoints if it were in a game.

Comment: If it's basic Java then I suggest just learning the fundamentals. When creating a game you have to take into account alot of things.

Comment: Also don't let the `static` scare you in my variable initialisation, the `Random` object could simply be initialised within the main method

Comment: @JulacOntina If you're new to StackOverflow, feel free to mark any answer you feel helped you most by ticking the check sign. Thanks